# Pc usb doesn't recognise devices

Tags: usb

I connected by USB port my Huawei p8 to my computer.

The phone is charging but the PC doesn't recognise the device, I thought it was a problem of my phone so I tried to connect a Samsung phone but the problem still exists.

I think it is a problem of my PC, what can I do?

Comment: After connecting the phone, did you open the notification that popped up on the phone and selected **Transfer files**? Have you tried different USB ports?

Comment: I tried to use the usb ports located on the back of the pc and it works. I suppose it's a problem of front usb ports.Thanks!